# How can I measure the latency between a Websphere Application and the DB?

Tags: java, oracle, websphere

I would like to measure the latency between my application which is running under Websphere and an Oracle DB. Is it possible to do this without making any changes to the Websphere application? For example, is there anything within the Performance Monitoring Infrastructure (PMI) or the Tivoli Performance Viewer that will give me this metric?

I see some possibilities, but nothing really seems to meet my needs.

Can I use the test database connection as detailed here https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-set-websphere-test-database-connections-prior-using-them ? If I tested every connection with "select 1 from dual" and found in some log how long it took to answer would that work?

What about using the admin console under Resource/Data Sources/Test Connection? This might work if it measured the time to check but I can't see where I would get the resulting latency.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep it simple: use a stopwatch in the code.  Start the timer before making the call, stop it when it returns, and calculate the duration in milliseconds.    Log the outcome and plot the distribution.

This will include the network round trip and the database processing time.

Is it important to separate the two?

If yes, you'll need a way to measure the database processing on the Oracle server separately.

Comment: yes, this would work, but it would mean that I would have to make changes to the codebase all the way into production. Roundtrip times will work ok, but I actually didn't want to make any changes to the Websphere application. I will edit the original question to make this clear.

Comment: I would guess that being able to measure performance in production would be a requirement, not a burden.   Sounds like you're blind about the performance of your app.  That's a bad place to be.